# How to convert List[List[Result]] into RDD[Result]?

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, rdd, data-conversion

- In my case Result is final case class
- I cannot use sc.parallelize() because my lists are very large and will crash the driver program.

Comment: If the `List[List[Result]]` is big enough to crash the driver, then your issue happens before the question of conversion to an `RDD` is meaningful. Where is the `List[List[Result]]` coming from? You should ask about how to convert from there directly to an `RDD`, skipping ever loading into one JVM's memory.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is too big to process in memory at one time, parallelize as many `List[Result]` (flattened) as you can at one time, persist if necessary, and then union the RDDs. This way, you'll get an RDD of all results without OOM.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that List will not scale. Since I was dealing with "big" data using Lists and List[List] was not the best idea because unlike RDD list are not sliced and distributed across executors. So using very large List probably crashes the executor nodes.

What I ended up doing is I updated by code to create RDD[List[Result]] and later used a flatMap to merge and get RDD[Result].